# TypeError: get_edge() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)

Tags: python, python-2.7, typeerror, self

I am working with a program to merge some DNA sequence, and this program got `TypeError: get_edge() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)`. Is there anyway to avoid it?

Here is the code:

```
def path(self, path, flip=False):
    from vic.utils.iter import pairwise
    oo = []
    if len(path) == 1:
        m = "Singleton {0}".format(path[0])
        oo.append((path[0].v, True))
        return m, oo
    edges = []
    for a, b in pairwise(path):
        av, bv = a.v, b.v
        e = self.get_edge((av, bv))
        if not oo:  # First edge imports two nodes
            oo.append((e.v1.v, e.o1 == ">"))
        last = oo[-1]
        assert last == (e.v1.v, e.o1 == ">")
        oo.append((e.v2.v, e.o2 == ">"))
        if flip:
            se = str(e)
            e.flip()
        else:
            se = str(e)
        edges.append(se)
    return "|".join(edges), oo
```

and the traceback:

```
 File "/home/wyim/vic/vic/graph.py", line 205, in path
    e = self.get_edge((av, bv))
TypeError: get_edge() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

Can you tell me what's wrong in here?

Comment: I suspect that alecxe is correct, but for completeness sake it would be helpful to include the `get_edge()` method here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters added `I suspect`, looks like [this](http://networkx.lanl.gov/archive/networkx-0.99/reference/generated/networkx.Graph.get_edge.html)..

Comment: That would be one candidate, yes.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect `get_edge()` requires two positional arguments, and you are passing only one, a tuple. Replace:

```
self.get_edge((av, bv))
```

with:

```
self.get_edge(av, bv)
```